# How to store and retrieve data in the form of graph

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, csv

I want to save some data on daily basis at the end of the day and always retrieve and show that data on my website in the form of line graph.

I have two questions:

1. Where should I store this data, in the database (MySQL) or any in CSV or JSON file? (Data is not private i.e anyone can see that.)
2. What would be the best way to retrieve data in the form of graph? I am using WordPress, so I might use a plugin.

Comment: What type of data are you seeking to store exactly?

Comment: @Optimae I need  Date,expected_hits(number),actual_hits(number). I just need these three data and want to draw line graph as date on y-axis and expected_hits and actual_hits on x-axis as line

Comment: Do you need to be able to manually set the `expected_hits` or are you using a formula to automatically calculate them?